# iOS' equivalent of Android's SharedPreferences

Tags: android, objective-c, ios

I am looking for the iOS equivalent of Android's [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  For the iOS people, SharedPreferences is an easy key value lookup available across multiple Activities and Views.

I need to get the user's name, age, and height and store it so that all my iOS views for this app can access it.  What is the best way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 27):

Take a look at `NSUserDefaults` ([docs link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` would be the equivalent of default `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store settings bundles. Here is a link to the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html